# Angular Equivalent to backbone.js listenTo/Trigger?

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js

I've been requested to convert an backbone.js app to an angular.js app and was just wondering if angular had anything similar to backbones .trigger/listenTo, where I could emit a trigger and fire off a function without knowing what function will handle that emit?

Comment: `$scope.$on()`/`$scope.$emit()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See angular's docs [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope) for more info on `$scope` events, but here's the basics:

```
var myObj = {};

$scope.$emit('someEvent', myObj);  // dispatches event upwards through the scope hierarchy
$scope.$broadcast('someEvent', myObj);  // dispatches event downwards to child scopes

$scope.$on('someEvent', function(e, data){
    // do something with data
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: do these calls get executed asynchronously or synchronously?

Comment: asynchronously.  just like all javascript events are.

Comment: that being said, in my experience, its pretty instantaneous